# Tails 2.3 not starting(stuck @ LSB , live-config) in Debian Jessie Virt-Manager (inside Win10 Virtualbox VM)

Tags: tails, linux, debian

I am (trying to) run Tails 2.3 via Virt-Manager inside a Debian Jessie guest in a Windows10 Virtualbox VM.

When I start to create a virtual machine per instructions on:
https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/virt-manager/index.en.html#index3h1
I see this:

> Warning: KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly.

Carrying on regardless(based on what I'm seeing in the forums etc.), according to the tails boot sequence(?) I see after `Welcome to Linux`:
`[ OK ] Started Apply Kernel Variables. 
A start job is running for LSB: AppArmor in... 5s/ no limit
A start job is running for live-config cont... 5s/ no limit`
... those last two "start job"s seem to be getting in the way of the boot, and my tails ends up never actually starting.

Anyone else experiencing this at all? any suggestions? Any way to change the "limit"
on the wait for LSB and live-config ? How critical are these?
Note, I have already (in the Debian guest) installed:
`virt-manager libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-bin qemu-kv`
... Happy to post any logs etc. to illustrate/clarify but just dunno what needs looking at right now.

Answer (score 1):

In **every** Linux you **must not rely on package-provided DKMS/VirtualBox modules**!! It's a common trouble-starter. Build them from guest additions ISO from source by hand, selecting appropriate version to your bits : 32 or 64. Then it will be just fine.